Contradiction upon tensor index lifting in Wikipedia
When it comes to the definition of $\gamma^5$ on Wikipedia (Wikipedia page: Gamma matrices)  there appears the following equation (Minkowski metric):
$$\gamma^5 = \ldots =\ldots = \frac{i}{4!}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma = - \frac{i}{4!}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu\gamma_\rho\gamma_\sigma$$
However, we deal with tensor indices, therefore tensor index lifting down and up should have no effect. In particular we have:
$$\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma = \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}\eta^{\gamma\rho}\eta^{\delta\sigma}\gamma_\alpha \gamma_\beta \gamma_\gamma \gamma_\delta = \epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} \gamma_\alpha \gamma_\beta \gamma_\gamma \gamma_\delta$$.
Upon renaming the indices $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ back to $\mu,\nu, \rho$ and $\sigma$ we get the definition of $\gamma^5$ without minus sign.
What is going on here ? It is actually quite confusing because both definitions are a priori possible depending on the definition of $\epsilon^{0123}$. But at least one should assume that once a convention is chosen that it is maintained in the same line of equations.

The Wiki page equation with the relative minus sign is   correct, but confusingly written. The definitions of the two Levi-Civita's are different: the downstairs $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} 
$ in the LH definition has been definied so that $\epsilon_{0123}=1$ while the upstairs $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$ is defined so that  $\epsilon^{0123}=1$.
Of course these are inconsistent in Minkowsli signature as they must have opposite signs. The wiki author should have used different symbols for their  two Levi-Civita's.

If it were as you said, the chain of equal signs is not correct. WP announces $\epsilon^{0123}=1$ and this is used after the 2. equal sign, so $\gamma^5=\frac{i}{4!}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma$ which in contradiction with the definition of $\gamma^5$ for $\epsilon^{0123}=1$ some lines above: $\gamma^5=-\frac{i}{4!}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma$. It seems to fix it WP sneaks in a minus sign which is inconsistent with the tensor index lifting in Minkowski metric.

I am reading the equations as the author  changing the definition of $\epsilon$ as they raise or lower the indices, so that,for the author $\epsilon_{abcd}= \epsilon^{abcd} (!)$ which is not standard, but is where the minus sign is being sneaked in. It's certainly confusing. I'd just edit the pages to fix it.

I know the answer now: Actually $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = -\delta^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$. So this way one gets a minus after the second equal sign which is carried through after the 4. equal sign without sneaking in an inconsistent minus sign before and after the 4. equal sign.  I found  the minus sign between the generalized kronecker and the product of 2 Levi-Civita's from another source: Sexl&Urbantke : relativity, groups and particles.

@mikestone, The only purpose of Levi-Civita $\epsilon_{abcd}$ or $\epsilon^{abcd}$ is to keep track of the order of indices $abcd$, nothing more and nothing less.  The sign of $\epsilon_{abcd}$ and $\epsilon^{abcd}$ should be INDEPENDENT of the spacetime signature. Therefore the convention adopted in Wiki as: $\epsilon_{abcd} = \epsilon^{abcd}$ is the RIGHT choice.

@ MadMax. This is an interesting viewpoint. I have always seen the indices raised and lowered with the metric tensor. The wiki article does seem to imply that the regard $\epsilon^{0123}=1$ as  a different convention from $\epsilon_{0123}=1$. Of course the Levi-Civita tensor differs by factors of $\sqrt g$ from the Levi-Civita symbol.
